# Test Class for testing controller twice

Tags: apex, unit-test, rest-api, code-coverage, httpcalloutmock

I have a test class below that is successful and covers accessing my controller with a callout:

```
  @isTest static void testUpdateOfPack(){
       MockPackageService mockRes = new MockPackageService();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mockRes);
        PageReference page = new PageReference('/package');
        page.getParameters().put('actId', GTRdata.grabAccount().id);
        Test.setCurrentPage(page);
        packController pack = new packController();
        Test.startTest();
        //Pack data is entered here
        //item pack is entered here
        pack.recalculate);
        pack.Reduction();
        //More pack updates here
        pack.save();
        Test.stopTest();
        itemPack = [SELECT ID, Price__c FROM item_package__c WHERE ID = :itempack.id];
        System.assertEquals(924.00, itempack.Price__c);
}
```

I need to also add a second "PackController pack2 = new PackController(); because when a user goes to edit the record, I need to write a test class to cover that things are being updated

```
   @isTest static void testUpdateofPack(){
       MockPackageService mockRes = new MockPackageService();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mockRes);
        PageReference page = new PageReference('/package');
        page.getParameters().put('actId', GTRdata.grabAccount().id);
        Test.setCurrentPage(page);
        packController pack = new packController();
        Test.startTest();
        //Pack data is entered here
        //itemPack is inserted as well
        pack.recalculate);
        pack.Reduction();
        //More pack updates here
        pack.save();
        itemPack = [SELECT ID, Price__c FROM item_package__c WHERE ID = :itempack.id];
        System.assertEquals(924.00, pack.Price__c);
    PageReference pageTwo = new PageReference('/pack');
        page2.getParameters().put('actId', GTRdata.grabAccount().id);
        Test.setCurrentPage(page2);
        packController pack2 = new packController();
        //More pack updates here
        pack2.save();
        itemPack = [SELECT ID, Price__c FROM item_package__c WHERE ID = :itempack.id];
        System.assertEquals(950.00, itempack.Price__c);
```

However now, I get an error at packController pack2 = new packController();:

> System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

Do I have to implement test.setMock again? Or how would I tackle this?

Comment: try to move this line `packController pack2 = new packController();` outside `Test.stopTest()`

Answer (score 1):

If possible, use two unit tests. The first does the method with the callout, the other with everything else. You may need to use [@TestVisible](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_testvisible.htm) on some of the attributes to manipulate the controller's internal state. This makes it easier to provide *real* coverage, including validating logic, instead of just a plain code-coverage/smoke-screen test. The error regarding not being able to call out after a DML operation is rather easily solved by using multiple tests. Also, you can use [@TestSetup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_testsetup_using.htm) to set up your data, reducing common DML operations.